# How to focus the list items in the list view based on certain conditions?

Tags: wicket

I have a list view in my page  with list of items on page load and  I need to focus the list items in the list based on the user search  in a text field on form submit..can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not tell us what kind of HTML elements should be `focused` - normal `div`s/`span`s or form elements like `input`s.

If you need to focus a normal element, i.e. to highlight it, then you just need to CSS decorate it. You can do this via:

```
listItem.add(AttributeModifier.append("style", "border: 1px red solid", ";"));
```

or

```
listItem.add(AttributeModifier.append("class", "myHighlightClass", " "));
```

The above will add CSS `style` or `class` attribute to the HTML element with `wicket:id` for the ListView.

If you need to focus an HTML input/select element then you need to execute JavaScript like `$('#yourInputId').focus()`.
You can do it in Wicket's `#renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)` method:

```
response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('#" + textField.getMarkupId() + "').focus()"));
```